# Double quotes in output file when running intellij jar in oozie workflow

Tags: hive, oozie-workflow, hive-query

I have created an oozie XML workflow to fetch data from a hive database table and export to CSV file. Oozie workflow has three actions as below

1. Executing Jar file created from intelliJ
2. Success email
3. Failure email

Jar file is generated from IntelliJ from a maven project. In the project I'm using `random.hql` file. Below query is present in the `random.hql` file

```
SELECT CONCAT(EMPLOYEEID,NAME,SALARY,AGE) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Oozie worklflow runs without issues and creates CSV file in the output directory. Data in file is as below

```
"_C0_"

"01267LSURESH3000026"
```

My question is how to remove double quotes(") which is at the starting and ending of the string?

Can this be done in the hive query itself? Also let me know if there is a way I can avoid column name(`_C0_`) in output file.

I would just want output as below:

```
01267LSURESH3000026
```

Comment: How are you writing CSV?

Comment: In oozie xml spark action , I am giving output format as CSV .